# Is there a way to tell how long it will be until my population grows?

Tags: stellaris

I've built some Hydroponics Farms on my home planet in *Stellaris* and am currently making a surplus of 5 food. I know this will eventually lead to an increase in population, but I'm not really sure when that will happen. Is there anywhere that shows when your next population increase will occur? It would help me decide whether or not to build more Hydroponics Farms, or just stay where I'm at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy!  Check out that little blue bar:

[image: Stellaris population graph]

Comment: Additionally in the planet overview you can hover over the the Pop-number and it will show you this information in a percentage form.